# Tkinter, changing a button and its command

Tags: python, tkinter

We have a button that calls function A. We want function A to change the image of that button and to change its command to call function B instead of A. How to do that? We can't have two buttons at the same time.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the button with the configure function.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def newFunc():
    print ("newclick")

def callback():
    print ("oldclick!")
    b.configure(image=image_new, text = "New button text", command=newFunc)

image_old = PhotoImage(file=your_imagepath)
image_new = PhotoImage(file=your_second_imagepath)
b = Button(master, image=image_old, text="Button Before click", command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```